# Android - fetch specific data by email login mysql

Tags: java, php, android, mysql

I have an application that can log in and register, and this application can read data from the database, but I get all the data from all users, how do I get the data that matches the user who is logged in?

this is my API and SharedPref

```
 <?php
 require_once('dbConnect.php');
 if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='GET') {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM farm ORDER BY SN" ;
    $res = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
    $result = array();
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res))
      {
      array_push($result, array('no'=>$row[0], 'username'=>$row[1], 
      'SN'=>$row[2]));
      }
 echo json_encode(array("value"=>1,"result"=>$result));
 mysqli_close($con);
 }
?>
```

this the code on Sharedpreference

```
public class SharedPrefManager {

public static final String SP_PREF = "etSmartAgriculture";
public static final String SP_EMAIL = "etUsername";
public static final String SP_ALREADY_LOGGEDIN = "spAlreadyLoggedIn";

private SharedPreferences sp;
private SharedPreferences.Editor spEditor;

public SharedPrefManager(Context context){
    sp = context.getSharedPreferences(SP_PREF, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    spEditor = sp.edit();
}

public void saveSPString(String keySP, EditText value){
    spEditor.putString(keySP, String.valueOf(value));
    spEditor.commit();
}

public void saveSPInt(String keySP, int value){
    spEditor.putInt(keySP, value);
    spEditor.commit();
}

public void saveSPBoolean(String key7SP, boolean value){
    spEditor.putBoolean(key7SP, value);
    spEditor.commit();
}


public Boolean getSPSudahLogin(){
    return sp.getBoolean(SP_ALREADY_LOGGEDIN, false);
}

/**
 * Get stored session data
 * */
public HashMap<String, String> getUserDetails(){
    HashMap<String, String> user = new HashMap<String, String>();
    // user email id
    user.put(SP_EMAIL, sp.getString(SP_EMAIL, null));



    // return user
    return user;
}
}
```

Comment: i would assume you need a `where` clause in the query, but we dont know your data structure

Comment: I use recyclerview to show the data on Android

Answer (score 0):

For getting specific user details information you need to change your SQL queries. I am not sure about your database table structure. You need to select that user information which user email will match with your passing email: **SP_EMAIL.**

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM farm WHERE user_email = SP_EMAIL ORDER BY SN";
```

Here you can get the complete tutorial of login and registration, also storing user information after login. Please go through this [tutorial](https://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-login-and-registration-with-php-mysql-and-sqlite/). Hopefully It will help you.